# TypeError: create() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context' 

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I got an error like this:

> **TypeError: create () got multiple values ​​for keyword argument 'context'**

This is the code:

```
mov_id = self.create(cr, uid, ids, {'so_ids':so, 'product_ids':product},context=context)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: In which model are you trying to use create function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a record, the parameters are cursor, user_id, dictionary of values and context.
for example

```
mov_id = self.create(cr, uid, {'so_ids': so, 'product_ids': product},context=context)
```

create doesnt take any ids, if you are trying to use copy, then use

```
mov_id = self.copy(cr, uid, ids, {'so_ids':so, 'product_ids':product},context=context)
```

Comment: sorry...I just checked.. yes it can..., but the "id" doesn't exists in database, I mean **write_uid** doesn't exists. but if I try like this   `return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'so_ids':"Test"}, context=context)` the **write_uid** exists

Comment: In OpenERP create function doesn't takes any parameter like id or list of ids, For write,read and copy function takes list of ids and a dictionary with values to update as parameters. When creating a record with create function, in database 'create_uid' will be the 'uid' that you are passing and it will not have a write_uid; when you want to update a record they use write function,then in database the 'write_uid' field will have the value of 'uid'.

Comment: Hello JC have look the ORM methods at following link : http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html

Answer (score 1):

> self.create(cr, uid, {'so_ids':"Test"}, context=context)

This is the syntax for create method.

If you want to add 'write_uid' just add {'write_uid': ur_id} in dictionary in create method. 
In create method no 'id' or 'list of ids' is required.