# Odoo, Python: TypeError: info() got multiple values for keyword argument 'title'

Tags: xml, python-2.7, typeerror, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to use this Odoo addon:

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/warning_box/

https://github.com/ingadhoc/odoo-addons/tree/8.0/warning_box

to display some messages.

The install page says:

> usage return self.pool.get('warning_box').info(cr, uid, title='The
>   title', message='the message')

Since the code is written in V8.0 style, I think this is wrong. I've tried it anyway and it gave errors about cr and uid.

I then tried it like this:

```
self.env['warning_box'].info(self, title='The title', message='the message')
```

This gives me this error:

> TypeError: info() got multiple values for keyword argument 'title'

This is the python code of the Odoo addon:

```
WARNING_TYPES = [('warning', 'Warning'), ('info', 'Information'), ('error', 'Error')]

class warning_box(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'warning_box'
    _description = 'warning_box'
    _req_name = 'title'

    type = fields.Selection(WARNING_TYPES, string='Type', readonly=True)
    title = fields.Char(string="Title", size=100, readonly=True)
    message = fields.Text(string="Message", readonly=True)

    @api.multi
    def message_action(self):
        self.ensure_one
        message_type = [t[1]for t in WARNING_TYPES if self.type == t[0]][0]
        res = {
            'name': '%s: %s' % (_(message_type), _(self.title)),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_id': self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_id(
                'warning_box.warning_box_form'),
            'res_model': 'warning_box',
            'domain': [],
            'context': self._context,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
            'res_id': self.id
        }
        return res

    @api.model
    def warning(self, title, message):
        record = self.create({'title': title, 'message': message, 'type': 'warning'})
        return record.message_action()

    @api.model
    def info(self, title, message):
        record = self.create({'title': title, 'message': message, 'type': 'info'})
        return record.message_action()

    @api.model
    def error(self, title, message):
        record = self.create({'title': title, 'message': message, 'type': 'error'})
        return record.message_action()
```

I have been looking up the error and found these 2 pieces of information:

[class method generates "TypeError: ... got multiple values for keyword argument ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950054/class-method-generates-typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument)

[TypeError: create() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481076/typeerror-create-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument-context)

I've tried to understand it and to apply it to my situation, but I can't get it working...
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

**edit for Forvas:**

I call the function like this now:

```
return self.env['warning_box'].error(title='The title', message='the message')
```

This didn't give any errors with the code above.

Now I've changed def message_action like you said.
For this:

```
form_view_id = self.env.ref(
        'your_module_name.your_form_view_xml_id').id
```

I used:

```
form_view_id = self.env.ref(
    'warning_box_git.warning_box_form').id
```

Just to make sure, did you mean module name or model name?
My model (class) is warning_box and my module name is warning_box_git (name of the folder of the module). Did I do this correct?

Either way I keep getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'warning_box' object has no attribute 'error'

This is my XML:

```
<openerp> 
    <data> 
        <record id="warning_box_form" model="ir.ui.view">
             <field name="name">warning_box.form</field> 
             <field name="model">warning_box</field>
             <field eval="20" name="priority"/> 
             <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
                 <form string="Warning">
                    <field name="message" nolabel="1"/> 
                    <footer>
                        <button string="OK" class="oe_highlight" special="cancel"/>
                    </footer> 
                 </form> 
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_warning_box">
            <field name="name">Warning Box</field>
            <field name="res_model">warning_box</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="warning_box_form" />
            <field name="target">new</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Do you have any idea how to solve the error?

**edit 2 for Forvas:**
I made a stupid indentation mistake. That error is gone now.
But still, it doesn't show any pop-ups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass `self` as a parameter.

```
self.env['warning_box'].info(title='The title', message='the message')
```

You "pass" it when you are calling the model from `self`.

**EDIT**

Try with the next code:

```
@api.multi
def message_action(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    message_type = [t[1]for t in WARNING_TYPES if self.type == t[0]][0]
    form_view_id = self.env.ref(
        'your_module_name.your_form_view_xml_id').id
    return {
        'name': '%s: %s' % (_(message_type), _(self.title)),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'views': [(form_view_id, 'form'), ],
        'res_model': 'warning_box',
        'context': self._context,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
        'flags': {'action_buttons': True},
    }
```

Comment: But there's still no pop-up. Do you also have any idea why that might be?

Comment: I've edited my answer @RobbeM, take a look of what I do when I want to open a pop-up (Obviously replace *your_module_name.your_form_view_xml_id* by your data).

Comment: Thank you for your effort. However I'm getting a new error now... I've edited my OP with the details.

Comment: I think the problem must be in the decorators. You call `message_action` from other methods which have `@api.model`, try to remove that and write `@api.multi` instead, or `@api.one`.